# Where did Euler prove 'his' theorem on homogeneous functions?

Tags: mathematics, notation, calculus, euler

Where in Eulers writings can I find a proof of his [homogeneous function theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homogeneous_function#Positive_homogeneity): *$y$ is a homogeneous function of degree $k$ in $x_1,\ldots,x_n$ iff  $ky = \sum_{i=1}^n x_i\frac{\partial y}{\partial x_i}$*? None of the sources I've seen cite him.

I'm curious because in his *Introduction to the analysis of the infinite* he defines a homogeneous function as one "in which each term has the same degree" and goes on to discuss several examples (not just polynomials). But I don't see him writing down the "modern" definition 
$$f(\lambda{\bf x})=\lambda^k f({\bf x})$$
 and wonder how he would prove the result without this. (I know he used function notation, but very rarely.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Lucky you! (or me :-) ).  This question was answered a while back on [Math.SE](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3457070/where-did-euler-first-write-about-homogeneous-function)

> I found his original thoughts in the translated version of
>   "Institutiones calculi differentialis cum eius usu in analysi
>   finitorum ac doctrina serierum, volume 1", chapter 7. The translation
>   is called "Foundations of Differential Calculus" and a link is found
>   here https://link.springer.com/book/10.1007%2Fb97699 .

Comment: Thanks. So it starts in par. 220 and indeed he does not use $f(x)$ notation!

Comment: Though as far as I can tell from that book he only proves the direction $\implies$.